# Time-travelling Index algorithm

Tags: arrays

You're given an array of characters and a current index:

```
["A", "B", "C", ... "Z"]
  ^
```

For every hour `h`, the index moves forward by 1. For example, after 2 hours, the index will be at `C`:

```
["A", "B", "C", ... "Z"]
            ^
```

If the index reaches the final element of the array, the next index advancement brings it back to the starting element.

Write a function that computes the element at the index on any particular hour.

---

Attempts:

#1 Use a circular buffer, storing the elements in the array and advancing the index by `h`. This gives us the correct answer, but needs to rely on an intermediary data structure

Hoping there's a mathematically pure way of doing this.

Comment: Please specify the language and show what've you attempted instead of pasting the whole question here.

Comment: Added attempts. I'm not looking for a solution for any specific language, more interested in the algorithm itself.

Comment: Isn't this can simply be achieved by returning array[input - 1] based on the time input by the user or the current hour? or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: Apologies, missed a crucial detail. Added "If the index reaches the final element of the array, the next index advancement brings it back to the starting element."

Answer (score 0):

Let:

- `c` = current index
- `t` = number of hours
- `n` = number of elements in array
- `a` = the array

The index, relative to current index, after `t` hours have elapsed, is given by:

```
(c + t) % n
```

Once you have the index, you can access the relevant element in the array.

```
char fn(char[] a, int c, int t)
{
    int i = (c + t) % n;
    return a[i];
}
```

Using the example from the question:

```
a = ["A", "B", "C", ... "Z"]
c = 0
t = 2
n = 26
i = (0 + 2) % 26 = 2
a[2] = "C"
```